# El servidor Apache me devuelve un error al intentar subir un simple archivo en Mac

Tags: java

Felicidades por la página, yo la utilizo mucho para resolver problemas.

Como se puede observar, Apache me devuelve un error al intentar subir un simple archivo (una foto en este caso). NO SE QUE ES LO QUE ESTOY HACIENDO MAL!!! El mensaje de retorno dice: No es válida la localización [/Users/upload] de carga temporal. Estoy utilizando Apache 8.5 y Eclipse EE.

En otro ordenador (Windows) no he tenido ningún problema, pero con Mac, si.

Espero resolver el problema lo antes posible.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
@WebServlet("/SubeArchivo")
@MultipartConfig(location="/Users/upload", maxFileSize =10485760L)
public class SubeArchivo extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public SubeArchivo() {
    super();

}
protected void comodin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    String submit=request.getParameter("enviar");
    String descripcion =request.getParameter("descripcion");
    Part parteArchivo=request.getPart("archivo");
    String nombreArchivo=parteArchivo.getSubmittedFileName();
    parteArchivo.write(nombreArchivo);

    long tamanio=parteArchivo.getSize();
    String tipo=parteArchivo.getContentType();

    //creacion del html de salida
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    if(submit!=null) {
        try (PrintWriter out=response.getWriter()){
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet SubirFichero</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1> Opercion realizada con exito </h1>");
            out.println("<table border=1px>");
            out.println("<tr><td>Descripcion del archivo</td> 
</tr>"+descripcion+"</td></tr>");
            out.println("<tr><td>Archivo subido</td><td> 
<b>C:\\upload\\"+nombreArchivo+"</b></td></tr>");
            out.println("<tr><td>Tamaño del arcivo</td> 
</tr>"+tamanio+"</td></tr>");
            out.println("<tr><td>Tipo de archivo</td></tr>"+tipo+" 
</td></tr>");
            out.println("</table></body></html>");  
        }
    }   
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    comodin(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    comodin(request, response);
}
```

Comment: En una Mac, tienes que darle permisos de escritura a las carpetas donde vayas a querer utilizar para esos fines.

Comment: Muchas gracias @fredyfx. Fue un buen comienzo para solucionar el problema, aunque ahora se me presentan otros a medida que el Servlet va creciendo...

Comment: ¿entonces, se arregló con los permisos? Considera siempre desarrollar en carpetas de nombre corto y ruta corta como C:\Dev o C:\Proyectos o algo así

Comment: Si, como te digo, se solucionó con eso y con un cambio de ruta ya que el directorio raíz tenía problemas de permisos y preferí no dárselos y crear subdirectorios. Esto se trata de un formulario con diferentes campos, el último de ellos es un archivo y en caso de errores es necesario "repintar" estos mismos. En caso de que todos los campos cumplan las validaciones codificadas, hacer un eco de esos parámetros. Soy estudiante de programación y el problema es que en clase tengo Windows y yo en casa tengo un Mac, con lo que los errores que surgen se multiplican por dos.

Comment: ¡Enhorabuena! entre más errores soluciones, más capacitado saldrás :D

Answer (score 0):

En la Mac, dale permisos de escritura a la carpeta donde vas a guardar los archivos, en entornos derivados de UNIX (Mac, GNU/Linux) se tiene que asignar los permisos "correctamente" para que funcione como se espera.